# Get the lifetime of a class object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, time

I'm trying to implement a class like this:

```
class A:

   # some functions..

   def foo(self, ...)
       # if self has been instantiated for less than 1 minute then return
       # otherwise continue with foo's code
```

and I'm wondering, is there a way to implement a function like `foo()`?

Comment: cant get what you mean by `if self has been instantiated for less than 1 minute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be to store the timestamp of the creation as instance attribute:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time_created = datetime.now()

    def foo(self):
        if datetime.now() - self._time_created < timedelta(minutes=1):
            return None
       # do the stuff you want to happen after one minute here, e.g.
       return 1

a = A()
while True:
    if a.foo() is not None:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

class A:

   # some functions..
   def __init__(self):
       self._starttime = datetime.now()

   def foo(self):
       # if self has been instantiated for less than 1 minute then return
       # otherwise continue with foo's code
       if (datetime.now() - self._starttime).total_seconds() < 60:
           print "Instantiated less than a minute ago, returning."
           return
       # foo code
       print "Instantiated more than a minute ago, going on"
```

A variable is used to store the calling time of the object constructor and then used to differentiate the function behaviour.

If you run

```
a = A()
sleep(3)
a.foo()
sleep(61)
a.foo()
```

you get

```
$ python test.py
Instantiated less than a minute ago, returning.
Instantiated more than a minute ago, going on
```